# Getting id from mysql array

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm running a query that returns the following array ($array) when I executie print_r on it:

> Array ( [0] => Photo Object ( [id] => 105 [name] => .png [extention]
>   => _klein [tags] => 4 [target_file] => [imagelib_id] => 1))

How do I access the id value. It should be just $array['id']; right? I'm getting no value at all out of this

**Solution!**
$array[0]->id;... Because it's an object you have to access it like an object... This returns the id of object 0. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: That array only has one element, a "Photo Object" which has an "id".

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, you could access the `'id'` value as follows:

```
$array[0]['id'];
```

It's multidimensional array. First nested array is `0`. You must refer to it accordingly!

Comment: Echoing this returns another array, but instead of Photo Object being [0], it is set to [1].

Comment: Try running `print_r(array_values($array)[0]['id']);`

Comment: Hm, the [0] to [1] was because I added another photo and thus another photo object. Running that will stop my script from continueing btw.

Comment: Post your complete array that come from `SQL` results to http://ideone.com and will see what can be done!

Answer (score 0):

your array name is $array then

```
 echo $array[0]['id'];
```

gives you id value

Answer (score 0):

Because your first item is a Photo object, I would do this (considering id is public):

```
// $array = Array ( [0] => Photo Object ( [id] => 105 [name] => .png [extention] => _klein [tags] => 4 [target_file] => [imagelib_id] => 1))
var_dump(reset($array)->id);
```

reset() resets the internal pointer, so always pics the first element, this is nice when your array starts at another index, say 4.

Comment: Can you show us what the Photo object is then? We're in the dark when it comes to that :P

Comment: Every new Photo object is a new file and record in the database. So if I add another photo there will be another object created and thus will the key increment from [0] to [1].

Comment: vardump on the array gives:
    array(2) { [0]=> object(Photo)#8 (11) { ["id"]=> string(3) "106" ["name"]=> string(8) "test.png" ["extention"]=> string(6) "_klein" ["tags"]=> string(1) "v" ["target_file"]=> NULL ["imagelib_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["imagelib"]=> NULL